# Nikto: this might be interesting... file redirects

Tags: web-scanners

What does Nikto's "this could be interesting" log mean?

It identified a file (say, admin.html) as potentially interesting. However, when I wget or attempt to access this file in a browser, it just redirects me to the index.

How does Nikto find these files in the first place? Is it possible to see the GET request that found them? How can I access these files?

Comment: +1 I sometimes find the output of nikto confusing as well. I haven't yet discovered an option for "Show requests and responses for all printed findings, but for nothing else" (ie not verbose or similar, which just prints too much irrelevant info).

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [relevant section](https://github.com/sullo/nikto/blob/7dfc2a207e7ef973167a26de6741d3a349d9b5fb/program/plugins/nikto_sitefiles.plugin) of source code:

```
# request by hostname
my ($res, $content, $error, $request, $response) = nfetch($mark, "/$file", "HEAD", "", "", "", "sitefiles");

if (($res == 200) && (!is_404("/$file", $content, $res, $response->{'location'})) && 
  ($content !~ /<html/i) && ($response->{'content-type'} ne 'text/html')) {    
    add_vulnerability($mark, "/$file: Potentially interesting archive/cert file found.", 740001, 0, "HEAD", "/$file", $request, $response);    
}

# request by ip    
($res, $content, $error, $request, $response) = nfetch($mark, "/$file", "HEAD", "", "", \%flags, "sitefiles");    
if (($res == 200) && (!is_404("/$file", $content, $res, $response->{'location'})) && 
  ($content !~ /<html/i) && ($response->{'content-type'} ne 'text/html')) {   
    add_vulnerability($mark, "/$file: Potentially interesting archive/cert file found. (NOTE: requested by IP address).", 740002, 0, "HEAD", "/file", $request, $response);    
}
```

We can see that a file is marked as "potentially interesting" if a HTTP HEAD request

- returns 200 OK
- doesn't return 404 Not Found
- returns content without HTML
- returns a Content-Type header without a value of text/html

Comment: please note that if the web application is SPA it will  return the index.html (200 OK) for any file it search for, so it will add_vulnerability for all files it search for  .